# Django - Loading dynamic Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to know information refer to the loading files in Django. First of all, it's pretty clear to load static files. So in my case, we have simple website, where one of the script generate dynamic content. That dynamic content, it's:

- List of folders,
- With one HTML file
- And JPG Images.

**And main tasks here - it's loading that HTML files, with images.**

---

That generated content, might be changed, as much, as I need. And in my example, I can put That Contents into `templates` folder, and load like the snippet below. But where all images are missing. So I need to put that HTML files to the `templates` folder in project, and images to the separated `static` folder, to load them.

**Problem** here, that I want to locate Generated Source in some single and separated  path, but keep possibility to load HTML, with images.

```
## Ex. including HTML page (which should located in templates)
    <div class="container">

        {% include "stories/Princess_Run_Story/Princess_Run_Story.html" %}

    </div>


## Ex. loading IMG file(which should located in static)
     <img class="first-slide" 
              src= "{% static '/workbook/images/galaxy_droid_1.jpg' %}" >
```

Comment: I realise that English is not your first language, but unfortunately this question is impossible to understand. What exactly are you trying to do, and what is wrong?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yup, sorry for that. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it will work, just you need to send dynamic image date from View while calling this snippent. put following detail in proper path only.

{% include "stories/Princess_Run_Story/Princess_Run_Story.html" %}

Alternate Option:
Actually just call Ajax on click of button and prepare image date in snippet through backend and send snippet on Ajax success
Like below code in javascript:

```
there $('.container').html(snippet_data)
```

in backend:

```
render_data = {'image_data': image_data}
t = loader.get_template('stories/Princess_Run_Story/Princess_Run_Story.html')
html = t.render(RequestContext(request, render_data))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'html': html}), 'application/json')
```

Comment: "put following detail in proper path only", this exactly my question.

Comment: Plz. See above answer  i added alternate option also.